# Handler function in Controller

Tags: extjs

How to give a handler function On Controller. This is the code Used In View.This is

working.But i need this hanler function put on a Controller.

items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkbox',

```
                name: 'billingSameAsMailing',

                boxLabel: 'Same as Mailing Address?',

                hideLabel: true,

                checked: true,

                style: 'margin-bottom:10px',

                 id:'billingSameAsMailing',

        handler: function(me, checked) {

                    var fieldset = me.ownerCt;

        Ext.getCmp('billingStreet').setDisabled(checked);

        Ext.getCmp('bilcity').setDisabled(checked);

                }
```

Is It Possible?

Pls Help Me...

Answer (score 1):

Check out `control()` function http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control